# Long Exact Sequence in Group Cohomology Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, group-cohomology

[image]

How do you prove this? I have looked all around and am unable to find a real, in-depth proof.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg

Comment: @tkf I had the very same thought...

Comment: The two important ingredients are the Snake Lemma, and the exactness of $\operatorname{Hom}(F, \cdot)$ when $F$ is projective. Hopefully you can figure it out from there

Comment: @MSquared - To put things into context - from which book is your Theorem 21 above taken?  Where else have you looked? There are lots of sources! And what do you mean by 'a real, in-depth proof', and what is 'your' def of cohomology? Using injective resolutions? Using cochains? In any case, I don't remember, but I would think, for instance, that Weibel's book (intro to homological algebra) would be good [beware of errata, though, download the on-line corrections]...

Answer (score 2):

Consider a projective resolution $$\cdots \to P_i \to P_{i-1} \to \cdots \to P_0 \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
Let \begin{eqnarray*}
A^i&=&{\rm Hom}_G(P_i,A),\\
B^i&=&{\rm Hom}_G(P_i,B),\\
C^i&=&{\rm Hom}_G(P_i,C).
\end{eqnarray*}

Then form the diagram:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
&&\vdots &&\vdots&&\vdots&&\\
&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d\\
0&\to&A^i&\to& B^i&\to& C^i&\to&0\\
&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d\\
0&\to&A^{i+1}&\to& B^{i+1}&\to& C^{i+1}&\to&0\\
&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d&&\downarrow d\\
&&\vdots &&\vdots&&\vdots&&\\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $d$ is precomposition with the relevant map from the resolution and the horizontal maps are post-composition with the maps $A\to B$ and $B\to C$.

${\bf Step\,\, 1}$ You need to check that this diagram commutes and then use the projective property of the $P_i$ to show that the rows are exact.

Once you have done that, define the Snake map on cocycles in $C^i$ as follows:

(1) Take a preimage of your cocycle in $B^i$ (as in the film clip).

(2) Apply $d$.

(3) Take a preimage in $A^{i+1}$.

${\bf Step\,\, 2}$ Check that each of those moves was possible, and that the end result is well defined up to coboundaries in $A^{i}$.  Also make sure that you end up with a cocycle.

${\bf Step\,\, 3}$ Check that the resulting sequence of maps on homology (induced from the horizontal arrows) is exact.

There are a lot of little things to check at each stage, but you should find it really satisfying.  If you get stuck on anything specific, drop a comment.